# Twitter Ads API

Tags: php, laravel, api, twitter, ads

Getting issues to fetch **ready Custom Audience** from API. I have created a audience with 700 user's email list. After couple of hours it start showing ready into Ads Manager but when trying to fetch the same from API, `is_targetable` is still false. If this the correct key to identify custom audience is ready?

## Twitter API

```
https://ads-api.twitter.com/5/accounts/{{account_id}}/tailored_audiences/38onh
```

## Response Body

```
{
   "request": {
       "params": {
           "tailored_audience_id": "38onh",
           "account_id": "18ce54uwag1"
       }
   },
   "data": {
       "targetable": false,
       "name": "Custom Audience - Verify Status-02",
       "targetable_types": [
           "CRM",
           "EXCLUDED_CRM"
       ],
       "audience_type": "CRM",
       "permission_level": "READ_WRITE",
       "is_owner": true,
       "id": "38onh",
       "reasons_not_targetable": [
           "TOO_SMALL"
       ],
       "created_at": "2019-07-18T13:56:04Z",
       "updated_at": "2019-08-31T12:23:46Z",
       "partner_source": "OTHER",
       "deleted": false,
       "audience_size": null
   }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of active audience https://prnt.sc/p24ku5